# Issue in creating Chrome driver with version 3,14 C# Selenium

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, ui-automation, selenium-grid

Code for grid driver initiation,

My Code is,

```
case "chrome":
                                              
                        ChromeOptions driverOptions;
                        driverOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                       
                        driverOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.EnableProfiling, true, true);
                        try
                        {
                            m_driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://mygridip:4444/wd/hub"), driverOptions.ToCapabilities());
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                           Console.WriteLine( e.Message);
                        }
```

Error in console,

[image]

> System.MissingMethodException   HResult=0x80131513   Message=Method
> not found: 'Void
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(System.Uri,
> OpenQA.Selenium.DriverOptions)'.

I am new to c# selenium with 3.14, trying to migrate my code from 2.48 to 3.14, But after upgrate to 3.14 its not working on the first step itself, getting an error while initiating driver. Help is really appreciated.

Comment: Getting this error too.. System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void OpenQA.Selenium.DriverOptions.set_PlatformName(System.String)'..

Comment: I'm running the above code and I'm not receiving the error message. Can you try and use the latest grid version: selenium-server-4.1.1.jar from here: https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/. Maybe your grid version is pretty old and the methods have been deprecated and removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be Selenium 2.48 installed / compiled, hence you see the exception noted, as your code is being executed against it and cannot find method for RemoteWeDriver. The method RemoteWebServer was introduced in version 3 of Selenium:

```
System.MissingMethodException HResult=0x80131513 Message=Method not found: 'Void OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(System.Uri, OpenQA.Selenium.DriverOptions)'.
```

You more than likely have multiple version jars of selenium in your classpath etc. Ensure all components of version 2.48 have been removed / uninstalled cleanly. Then re-install / compile v3.14 and execute code again